# How to include the App.config info in a reference executable in .NET?

Tags: .net, app-config

I have one executable project, let's say `A`, which is launching another executable project `B`in the run. In order to have a `B.exe` in A's current working folder, I add B as A's reference so that after the compilation a `B.exe` will be copied into `A`'s folder. However, I noticed the configuration that I make for `B` is not copied or generated in A's folder (there is no B.exe.config file in `A`'s folder, only `B.exe`), and hence the stuff such as tracing for `B` is not configured correctly.

I can of course copy the `B.exe.config` manually to `A`'s folder, but I bet there is some automatic way to do that. Could anybody help me?

Comment: How does A.exe start B.exe? If you don't use it in code don't make a reference. Make a post build script (or something) that copies it to the correct folder. In general there's only one .config file per appdomain that's why it isn't copied the configuration of B should be in A.exe.config when it is referenced (this is not an automatic process).

Comment: @the_ajp Thanks for your reply. I am indeed starting B.exe in code because of 2 reasons: 1) A.exe is an 64bits app and B.exe is 32bits, so A.exe can't load B into it's app domain. 2) I want B.exe to be killed whenever A.exe exists. So do you think a post build script would be the best practice?

Answer (score 5):

You can use post-build events, or...

In Project A, add a link reference to B.exe.config. You do this by adding an existing item to the project. But, before pressing the Add button on the file dialog, press the down arrow on the right of the Add button and select "Add as Link." Then, set the file to copy to the output directory. In your project file, it will look something like this:

From ProjectA.csproj:

```
<None Include="..\ProjectB\bin\Debug\B.exe.config">
  <Link>B.exe.config</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

If you don't mind manually editing your project file, the included file can depend on the build configuration. The following works for builds (though VS2013 will not open the file when you double-click on the icon in the project tree.)

```
<None Include="..\ProjectB\bin\$(Configuration)\B.exe.config">
  <Link>B.exe.config</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any idea why this approach might not work on a Team Foundation Build Server

Comment: @pquest I do not, but I have another data point for you. I just tested it using VS 2015 and VisualStudio.com account with TFS 2015. It worked. In the log I can see it "copying file from ProjectB\bin\Release\ProjectB.exe.config to ProjectA\bin\Release\ProjectB.exe.config" and then later "copying from ProjectA\bin\Release\ProjectB.exe.config to the drop folder. I did use the $(Configuration) variable in my link to the configuration file.

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler solution would be to simply include the following in the csproj file. This includes the matching file extensions for the referenced files.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
      .pdb;
      .xml;
      .exe.config;
      .dll.config
    </AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions not recognized

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have 2 app.configs in your application directory. 
Visual studio will use the app.config of the launching project by default.

 You could create a post build event trigger where you copy the app.config but this would replace the original app.config (which i'm guessing contains data you need).
The best approach (aside from creating a clean dll + project architecture) is to manually merge all of project A's configuration data into project B's configuration data.

Comment: It wouldn't overwrite app.config because the app.config of b.exe will be called b.exe.config and not a.exe.config. And you basically copied my comment :(. Which I didn't post as an answer because we do not yet know how b.exe is used.

Comment: Didn't refresh the page before i submited but i can assure you i didn't commit plagiarism. I posted it as an answer because i felt that merging the 2 app.configs would fix his issue.

Comment: Alright :) hehe. It will and when not the post build event will.

Comment: @Kristof Thanks for your reply. Please also see my comment on my original post. Basically I can't merge A.exe and B.exe because they are one 64bits app and the other 32 bits. I can have B.exe.config, and in this scenario, I guess post build event is the only way?